# input[checked] CSS selector on radio input is not matching in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to apply a style to the label for a radiobutton with the CHECKED attribute, but everything I've tried fails to match on IE7.

Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fleb/jbh3nt95/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Ensure that + selectors work */
            input + span { color: blue; }

            /* Try [checked] alone */
            input[checked] + span { color: red; }

            /* Try selecting by value */
            input[checked="checked"] + span { color: green; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="x" /><span>One</span>
            <input type="radio" name="x" /><span>Two</span>
            <input type="radio" name="x" /><span>Three</span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

All SPANs' text are blue, but the first one is neither red nor green, in IE7 (both native and emulated in IE11). Will I need JS hack-arounds, or is there some trick to the CSS that I can employ to get this working?

Comment: You're testing it in emulated mode, so you're not getting it worked but if you test in real ie7 then it should work fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird.  IE7 supports attribute selectors (at least basic ones).  It must be something specific to the checked attribute.  If you change the checked attribute to ANY other attribute name (valid or not) the selector works.  Just try deleting the 'ed' to make it 'check' and both the existence and the equality selector work.  Not sure if this has to do with IE7 not setting the defaultChecked DOM (not HTML) attribute when the document is parsed.

> **Internet Explorer 8 and later**. In IE8 mode, parsing operations on the
>   checked content attribute always affect both the checked content
>   attribute and defaultChecked DOM attribute. For example,
>   removeAttribute('checked') sets both checked and defaultChecked to
>   false. Similarly, setAttribute('checked', 'checked') sets both DOM
>   attributes to true (as if the element was being re-parsed).

from:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533715(v=vs.85).aspx

If you have a large need (many elements) you could try Selectivizr - conditionally loaded for IE6-IE8 (what Selectivizr supports):

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/selectivizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you only have one or two places you could use a jQuery (or plain JavaScript) event handler.  This is not how I would normally write this, but my usually methods don't work in IE7; this was the **only** one that worked in IE7:

```
$('input[name="x"]').on('change', function(){
    $('input[name="x"]').siblings('span').removeClass('red');
    $(this).next('span').addClass('red');
});
```

CSS:

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you led me right to the answer with that bit about IE8. Using "input[defaultChecked]" as the attribute name, oddly enough, works. The only other oddity is to remove it using JS, you have to specifically do "removeAttribute('defaultChecked')", but that's good enough for my purposes. Thanks!